# Which one is recommended when putting a full width floating image?

Tags: floats, enumerate, marginpar

### Version 1

In this version, I put the full width floating image *outside* the `enumerate` environment.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\FullFig

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item
\lipsum[1]

\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
```

### Version 2

And in this version, I put it *inside* the `enumerate` environment.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]

\item
\FullFig
\lipsum[1]

\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
```

The complete MWE is given as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    vmargin=2cm,
    outermargin=9cm,
    innermargin=2cm,
    marginparwidth=7cm,
    marginparsep=20pt
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{temp}
\setcounter{temp}{0}

\newcommand\MarginFig{%
\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{This is an image A. This is subject to change without notice. Be careful my friend!}
\addtocounter{temp}{1}
\label{fig:\arabic{temp}}}}



\newcommand\FullFig{%
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \checkoddpage
  \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}%
    \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{% 
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}{%
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{This is an image B. This is subject to change without notice. Be careful my friend!}
        \addtocounter{temp}{1}
        \label{fig:\arabic{temp}}}}
\end{figure}
}


\begin{document}

% Version 1
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\FullFig

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item
\lipsum[1]

\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\newpage
% Version 2
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]

\item
\FullFig
\lipsum[1]

\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The PDF output of one version is slightly different from that of the other one. Which one is recommended when putting a full width floating image? Please give me the reason as well.

Note: This question was based on the quest to avoid possibility of bad behavior of floating images on the margin par and full width floating images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any layout differences between the two could be corrected if they need correcting.

The important thing is as far a practical the document markup should reflect the semantics of the document. In the first version the image is part of the surrounding text that gives context to the two enumerations. In the second version the image is part of the text of one item. So in your real text it should be clear which to use. With `lipsum` generated text it is not really possible to say.